# Hardware accelerated image conversion via WIC?

Tags: .net, wpf

We currently have a backend application that converts a couple ten thousand images per server per day and since this is currently being done mostly via .Net's System.Drawing functionality, we also have some 'limitations' when it comes to larger images (OutOfMemoryException, slow performance etc). Therefore we evaluated WIC codecs and their Encoders/Decoders a while back and got overall quite good results, but haven't made the actual switch & final implementation, yet.

However, a Q just popped up in my head and this is only semi programming related, but would WIC codecs benefit from a recent graphic card being installed in the system, just like WPF does? AFAIK WPF also uses WIC for image handling underneath and if plugging in a $500 card would in fact increase de/encoding times (it's a/numerous Win2003 server systems) it will pay off in a few days, but before purchasing a card to try and then maybe let it catch dust, I wanted to ask whether someone does know for a fact whether WIC would benefit here or not?